# ScrollView in Relative layout not working

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am getting problems with the scrollview. I am trying to get scrollview in my relativelayout. How can I keep scrollview in Relative layout. Please give me some suggestions to get rid from this problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Click for Images" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageSlide"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:src="@drawable/lightscph" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/NavImage"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:src="@drawable/google_maps_navigation" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textWebPage"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:text="Click for tivoli Website"
         android:textColor="#FF0000" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
         android:text="Navigate for location" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Set rootview as `ScrollView` and add your relative layout inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Click for Images" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageSlide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lightscph" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/NavImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/google_maps_navigation" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textWebPage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Click for tivoli Website"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:text="Navigate for location" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

thats it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ScrollView as a view:

e.g.:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/example_scrollview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    ...(ImageViews, Buttons etc)

    </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code as below..

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Click for Images" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageSlide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lightscph" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/NavImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/google_maps_navigation" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textWebPage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Click for tivoli Website"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:text="Navigate for location" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time in Eclipse Exceptions are raised while dragging widgets ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Copy paste this code and replace textviews with widgets you want